# com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.SqlException: [ibm][db2][jcc][10275][10041] Unsupported ccsid, encoding, or locale: "Cp037"

Tags: spring, hibernate, db2, websphere, tomcat8

I'm new to WAS server. I'm doing POC with Java 1.8, Spring(4.3.9.RELEASE), Hibernate(4.2.0), DB2 and WAS 8.5.5(installed java 1.8). Server started successfully but getting below exception while executing createQuery() statement.

```
 java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: Cp037
    at sun.io.Converters.getConverterClass(Converters.java:319)
    at sun.io.Converters.newConverter(Converters.java:373)
    at sun.io.ByteToCharConverter.getConverter(ByteToCharConverter.java:98)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.p.a(p.java:435)
    ... 132 more
2020-01-09 17:20:13 WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:143 - SQL Error: -99999, SQLState: 22021
2020-01-09 17:20:13 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:144 - [ibm][db2][jcc][10275][10041] Unsupported ccsid, encoding, or locale: "Cp037".
```

**It is working fine when i deploy the same into Tomcat**. Please help me on this to resolve,
let me know if any info needed. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions in this link?
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/439579/unsupported-ccsid-encoding-or-locale-cp037-errorco.html

Comment: Tried, but no luck. :(

Comment: Have you checked LANG (locale) setting of Tomcat environment and WAS?  If not, try set same and reboot machine to see if it picks up LANG or not.  It seems some kind of environment.issue.

Comment: @hidehy i didn't set any locale in both servers.

Comment: @sivabalaji I would try to set LANG=C or LANG=en_US.utf-8 explicitly for preventing inconsistent configuration.

Comment: @hidehy Thank you for your reply, i've tried with all the posibilities like, updated **en=UTF-8** in **encoding.properties** and in JVM generic arguments like **-Ddb2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3 -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US -Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8**, getting same exception. I've tried with the **simple JDBC query**, it's **creating ResultSet object but getting same exception when trying to print result set**. can you help me on this.

Comment: @hidehy, i've executed simple JDBC query with spring mvc in **Websphere Java 1.6**, it is not throwing any exception, the same throwing exception in Websphere Java 1.8**. is it Websphere java 1.8 installation issue?.

Answer (score 0):

It seems an known behavior of JDK 8.  Here is one of references:
**UTF-8 encoding/decoding problem in JDK 8**
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/utf-8-encodingdecoding-problem-jdk-8

Cause:

---

Starting from JDK 8 ,the input data to NIO UTF-8 decoder(Java API) should be of pure UTF-8. Till JDK 8 this rule was not strictly implemented and decoder was able to decode ill-formed UTF-8 byte sequence also. Decoder in JDK 1.8 will throw an exception if it encounters non UTF-8 data and the program cannot proceed with the execution.

---

Solution: (Does not work for Oracle JDK 8)

---

A new global property db2.jcc.alternateUTF8Encoding is introduced in JCC. This property can have value 1 and 0 ,the default value is 0 . If this property is set to 1 under IBM JDK 1.8 (db2.jcc.alternateUTF8Encoding=1) for UTF8 encoded data ,JCC uses UTF8J to decode .
This will help to avoid MalformedInputException during decoding. This is a global property and need to be configured in the property file. This property cannot be set using DataSource or Connection and works only with IBM JDK.

---

It is recommended review the article.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem, I resolved issue with below actions.

1. open websphere app server (WAS) admin console.
2. go to JDBC, JDBC providers, DB2 Using IBM JCC Driver, Class Path;
   ensure you have this entry: ${DB2_JCC_DRIVER_PATH}/db2jcc4.jar
3. go to Environment, Websphere variables, DB2_JCC_DRIVER_PATH should point to folder/path of latest db2jcc4.jar, mine is dated 6/13/2019